# GKSession receiveData: fromPeer: inSession: context: delay in receiving data

Tags: ios, timer, delay, gksession

I have created a timer app which used to run timer on multiple device if timer is stop on one device it has to reflect on the other device as well, i am using this delegate

```
- (void) receiveData:(NSData *)data
        fromPeer:(NSString *)peer
       inSession:(GKSession *)session
         context:(void *)context{
}
```

to get the value from the other device, its working fine except in some case its getting delay to receive the value and the timer value is different on different device.

Can any body help me out to make it exact time on both/multiple device without any delay.

Comment: Please show more code, including within your delegate method.